# Usage of しな particle

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-な, particle-し

As I've treated it, the しな at the end of the sentence is just し("not only, but also")+な(=ね). But Jisho.org says it could also mean "having just started...".

Is this true? Is there an example of this usage?

Comment: As a side note, しな at the end of a sentence can also be the short form of しなさい.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「Verb in 連用形{れんようけい} ("continuative form") + **しな**」

means:

> "just when (verb)ing", "on the occasion of", etc.

「しな」 is a suffix in this usage.

Examples:

「帰{かえ}り**しな**に雨{あめ}が降{ふ}ってきた。」 = Just when I was leaving, it started raining.

「寝{ね}**しな**にジャズを聴{き}くのが好{す}きだ。」 = I like listening to jazz just when I am going to bed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about し used to explain a reason, as in 「まだおきてないし、後で言っていいと思う」(for me it has an open action list connotation, I don't know if that's true or not...), and emphatic な.